# HTTP Request Content-Type different to the Server-Incomming Content-Type

Tags: php, http, post, header, content-type

first of all i created a test.php:

```
<?php var_dump( $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] );
```

I am sending a very simple HTTP-POST-Request like the following:

```
POST http://example.com/test.php
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
some text
 -- response --
200 OK
Server:  Apache/2.4.12 (Win64) mod_fcgid/2.3.9
X-Powered-By:  PHP/5.4.39
Content-Type:  text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

string(23) "text/xml; charset=UTF-8"
```

As you can see the sending charset i set to "ISO-8859-1" and the server stores in $_SERVER['Content-Type'] "UTF-8"

If the Request-Content is empty the response looks like:

```
POST http://example.com/test.php
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1

 -- response --
200 OK
Server:  Apache/2.4.12 (Win64) mod_fcgid/2.3.9
X-Powered-By:  PHP/5.4.39
Content-Type:  text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

string(28) "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1"
```

I test this on 2 different webservers (1x Zend CE Server, 1x Default Apache instance) and this happens on both webservers.

**Why the Webserver outputs a different Content-Type-Charset in $_SERVER['Content-Type'] as i have requested?**

I Ask this cause the PHP-Nusoap checks if the XML-Encoding equals the header-charset and so its different.

Comment: Does the content has BOM or the content is generated by PHP script ?

Comment: I generate the Request via the Firefox-HTTP-Requester Plugin (https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/httprequester/) and only type the Content inside the Plain-Text